# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile') at Bundler.transformFile

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npm-install, react-native-cli

I have updated `node` today and I'm getting this error:

```
error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
    at Bundler.transformFile (/Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:48:30)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.transform (/Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:101:12)
    at async processModule (/Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:18)
    at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (/Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:131:3)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async initialTraverseDependencies (/Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:114:3)
    at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (/Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:164:25)
    at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (/Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:94:16)
```

Other than that I haven't done anything unusual, so I'm not sure what to share. If I'm missing any info please comment and I'll add it.

While building the terminal also throws this error:

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at stableHash (/Users/.../node_modules/metro-cache/src/stableHash.js:19:8)
    at Object.getCacheKey (/Users/.../node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:593:7)
    at getTransformCacheKey (/Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/getTransformCacheKey.js:24:19)
    at new Transformer (/Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:48:9)
    at /Users/.../node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:22:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

My node, npx and react-native versions are:

- node: 17.0.0
- npx: 8.1.0
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Ran into the same issue with Node.js 17.0.0. To solve it, I downgraded to version 14.18.1, deleted `node_modules` and reinstalled.

Comment: After 3 days trying to find the issue, this did the job. I reinstalled the node LTS 14.8.1, and it solved the problem. Thanks

Comment:  It worked! Just remind that you've to delete node_modules and install it again using npm/yarn install

Comment: Is 14.8.1 the highest for which it works ? seems like a big step back to go back 3 versions...

Comment: I haven't tested it but according to other people in the thread version 16.13.0 is the latest version that will work fine

Comment: `nvm install 14.18.1` and even on an M1 Mac, this takes long enough to go on a coffee break, so consider going on a coffee break after running that command.

Comment: Anyboday has the idea why its happening with node 17+? I downgraded from 17.3.0 to node 16.3.0 and it started working.

Comment: So, I didn't understand why this was the solution and started digging into work arounds.  It's because Node 17+ isn't a Long Term Support (LTS) version.  Node only uses even numbers for LTS.  So, while 17 is the *latest* version, it doesn't mean it's the most bulletproof.  There are some workarounds as this has to do with how Node 17 is working with features that are deprecated by OpenSSL, but the tried and true is to go to the most recent LTS version of Node.  Lesson learned on my end!

Comment: I needed to downgrade node and also delete Xcode's DerivedData.

Comment: For my project i have install the node 16 and it works

Comment: Not worked for me :(

Answer (score 45):

you can resolve it by downgrading the node js

```
> nvm list // to see all available node version

> nvm install 16.13.0 // to install the version I wanted 

> nvm use 16.13.0  // use the installed version 
OR
> nvm alias default 16 // use the installed version as DEFAULT
```

Comment: I do the above steps and everything is fine. But when I try to build, it fails again. And if I close the terminal, and then I check again node version, it says 17?!

Comment: @FotiosTsakiris if you want your node version to persist, you can use ```nvm alias default 16.13.0```, that way your node version always stay at version 16.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. Actually, I tried something else and it worked. After I set `nvm use 16.13.0` I did `nvm uninstall 17.3.1` and then the project did build.

Comment: I also facing the same issue. I installed the latest version of node 18.12.0 but It's not working. So I have downgraded node version 16.13.0 and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 17):

Run:

```bash
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

To make connection to openssl

Answer (score 8):

I tried different node versions...same error.  Uninstalled and tried new versions of Android Studio...same error. Started brand new projects from scratch...same error. Deleted node_modules and ran npm i...same error.

Here's what did work for me.

Run

`npx react-native info`

Towards the top of that readout, it should say what Node version you are using. (it told me I was using Node: 17.xx.x in a stray node_modules folder.)

My fix was simply renaming that folder(in case deleting it breaks a different project). Now when I run `npx react-native info` it tells me the correct node version(16.13.1) and all my projects are running in the emulator again!

Answer (score 5):

This issue is due to the difference between node version you are currently using for example **node version 19** and node version used by the project.

To Solve this issue you need to downgrade or upgrade according to the node version used by project and your current node version.

you have to install node first and then then install `nvm (NODE VERSION MANAGER)`.
nvm is a node version manager with which you can install multiple node version

| CURRENT | LTS | OLD STABLE | OLD UNSTABLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19.2.0 | 18.12.1 | 0.12.18 | 0.11.16 |
| 19.1.0 | 18.12.0 | 0.12.17 | 0.11.15 |
| 19.0.1 | 16.18.1 | 0.12.16 | 0.11.14 |
| 19.0.0 | 16.18.0 | 0.12.15 | 0.11.13 |
| 18.11.0 | 16.17.1 | 0.12.14 | 0.11.12 |
| 18.10.0 | 16.17.0 | 0.12.13 | 0.11.11 |
| 18.9.1 | 16.16.0 | 0.12.12 | 0.11.10 |
| 18.9.0 | 16.15.1 | 0.12.11 | 0.11.9 |
| 18.8.0 | 16.15.0 | 0.12.10 | 0.11.8 |
| 18.7.0 | 16.14.2 | 0.12.9 | 0.11.7 |
| 18.6.0 | 16.14.1 | 0.12.8 | 0.11.6 |
| 18.5.0 | 16.14.0 | 0.12.7 | 0.11.5 |
| 18.4.0 | 16.13.2 | 0.12.6 | 0.11.4 |
| 18.3.0 | 16.13.1 | 0.12.5 | 0.11.3 |
| 18.2.0 | 16.13.0 | 0.12.4 | 0.11.2 |
| 18.1.0 | 14.21.1 | 0.12.3 | 0.11.1 |
| 18.0.0 | 14.21.0 | 0.12.2 | 0.11.0 |
| 17.9.1 | 14.20.1 | 0.12.1 | 0.9.12 |
| 17.9.0 | 14.20.0 | 0.12.0 | 0.9.11 |
| 17.8.0 | 14.19.3 | 0.10.48 | 0.9.10 |

To Install nvm please follow this [Link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/)

After this you can use the following nvm commands

```
nvm ls

// install specific version of node
nvm install 6.9.2

// set default version of node
nvm alias default 6.9.2

// switch version of node
nvm use 6.9.1
```

Comment: this is the most amazing and helpful answer. I was trying for three days and now my issue is resolved. thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

I am using Expo CLI with Node.js 17 and encountered the same error, and found the hint to the resolution (without downgrading Node.js) from here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33107#issuecomment-1042612307

However, instead of using `export` I installed `cross-env` as devDependency by running the following command: `npm i --save-dev cross-env`

Then I added the following command against `start` script in `package.json` under `scripts` section.

`"start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider expo start"`

Comment: This sounds like it's specifically for M1 Macs, based on the details I see in the link. Just labeling it here in case someone with a non-M1 expects it to solve their problem.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to install the node version manager:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

or:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

after installation, (if you are on Linux, close and reopen your terminal and) test it:

```
nvm -v
```

then install the node version 16.3.0:

```
nvm install 16.13.0
```

and ask the nvm to use this version:

```
nvm use 16.13.0
```

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from the node version. So, you will need to downgrade.

```
npx react-native info - // to see what node version your project uses.

nvm list // to see all available node version

nvm install 16.18.0 // to install the version you want

nvm use 16.18.0  // use the installed version
```

OR

```
nvm alias default 16 // use the installed version as DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty workaround (worked for me):

Add or update your package.json engines section with something like this to stop trying to build with Node 17.0.x Current, until you resolve the new OpenSSL PKCS8 format in the tls module:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "<17",
    "npm": "<8.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use an older osx version, you may need to add an nvm script to your zshrc file. Here is how to do so:

- in your terminal, type `open ~/.zshrc`
- in your `.zshrc` file, copy paste the following code:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

- go back to your terminal and run `source ~/.zshrc`

Now nvm will work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use node version `16.12.0`. **If you are using nvm, set default
   node version to `16.12.0`**. You can use following command

```
nvm alias default 16.12.0
```

2. Remove `node_modules` folder. You can use following command:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

3. Run the android run command again

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. Seems that the problem is due to version 17.x of Node.js. I solved downgrading to Node.js 16.12.0.

Comment: Node.js 16.13.0 is the latest version that works fine

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue. downgrade to version 16.13.1 from 17.3.0 and it worked great.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30700325)

Answer (score 1):

check your node version first using `nvm list`
uninstall the unnecessary version of node using `nvm uninstall version` change the version with the version number which is in use.
install the new version of node using `nvm install version_number`
use the installed version of node using `nvm use version_number` . Replace version_number with the version of node you have installed.

Comment: we do not know if the person is using nvm, since it i not mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

In case, you do the steps of @uzai sindiko and when you try to build, it fails again. And if you close the terminal, and then you check again node version, it says 17.3.1.

Then after you set `nvm use 16.13.0` do also `nvm uninstall 17.3.1` and then your project will be build.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try running this

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider 
npm run start:reset
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by updating updating node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node.sh @ L7

set -e change with

```
 set +e
```

P.S. Tried switching node from nvm to brew but that didn't made any difference.

I have tried all methods then I have found this one it solves my issue this below is refrenece

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36762#issuecomment-1535910492

Hope you can solve yours!

Answer (score 0):

Solution which works for me. Try to generate your main.jsbundle file with the below react-native command and verify it in your iOS folder.

1)Delete your pods folder and Podfile.lock file

2)run command

```
react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

3)After that run below command

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there. If you use `watchFolders` in metro.config.js, make sure you remove that key before building! That fixed it for me. It's useful if you are npm linking other packages but obviously eas build will not be able to find those links.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is struggling after reading the whole internet, for me the answer was to upgrade `react-native-svg-transformer` from [1.10 to 1.30](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer/releases). I had already tried things like passing `--openssl-legacy-provider` so that might also be necessary as well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when trying to build my Android app. My shell and Android Studio were using different node binaries.

I discovered this by running `which node` in my zsh shell terminal and in Android Studio's terminal. You can access the terminal in Android Studio with **View > Tool Windows > Terminal**.

In my case, Android Studio was using Node installed by Brew, while my zsh terminal was using Node managed by NVM. I don't use the Node binary installed by Brew, so I uninstalled it with `brew uninstall node`. Android Studio then used the same Node binary as my zsh terminal, and I could then build my Android app.

Answer (score -1):

Your metro might be probably running somehow.
Restart you computer before trying anything fancy

Answer (score -9):

I tried every solution on the internet but none of them helped, check if nothing's working then you must be having nodejs and node in your system. You can check on your terminal with `node -v` and `nodejs -v`

Uninstall nodejs

```
sudo apt-get uninstall nodejs
```

and you're good to go!

Comment: wtf mate!! uninstall nodejs seriously?