# node.js Failed to construct transformer: Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native

[image: error picture]

Have problems with installing the app on android emulator
OS: Windows 10
command doesn't solve the problem

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Comment: seems error in some prop 'transformFile' , at first delete your nodemudule and run install npm again and build . maybe some file lost

Comment: I was getting this exact error. I wrote up my solution over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71074259/18176334

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your node version is higher and not compatible with the version in react native

1. Firstly set your node version default to "v14.17.6"
2. Run this command `nvm alias default 16.14.2`
3. Clean node modules and do ./gradlew clean.
4. If iOS, delete podfile.lock and do pod install.

Answer (score 2):

A potential issue that's causing this problem could be related to your node version. If you're using nvm to manage your node versions and have recently updated to the latest release, consider reverting back to the version that version.
You can view the version in use with `nvm ls`. Change to an older LTS release with `nvm use <version_here>`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).