# in Bitrise node.js Failed to construct transformer: Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, metro-bundler, bitrise

whenever i try to build my react native app it is giving below mentioned error in bitrise virtual machine (apple silicon, silicon node default version is 18). but when i try to build using my local machine (apple intel, intel node default version is 16) it is working perfectly fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXmCL.png)

getting below error:

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at stableHash (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stableHash.js:19:8)
    at Object.getCacheKey (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:593:7)
    at getTransformCacheKey (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/getTransformCacheKey.js:24:19)
    at new Transformer (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:48:9)
    at /Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:22:29
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile').
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
    at Bundler.transformFile (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:48:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.transform (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:101:12)
    at async processModule (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:18)
    at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:131:3)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async initialTraverseDependencies (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:114:3)
    at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:164:25)
    at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:94:16)
    at async DeltaBundler.buildGraph (/Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler.js:50:5)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I tried the solution in the below link:
[node.js Failed to construct transformer: Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70234084/node-js-failed-to-construct-transformer-error-error0308010cdigital-envelope)
Most of them suggesting to downgrade node version to 16, but i dont want to downgrade my node version since when i build in virtual machine i will not be able to downgrade node version.

also tried solution from below link:
[Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported (Node.js v19.4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167770/error-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported-node-js-v19-4-0)
still it didnt work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [solution](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/1051#issuecomment-1698166680) fir iOS builds

```
set -e
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openss1-legacy-provider # add env variable here
WITH_ENVIRONMENT="../node_modules/react-native/scripts/xcode/with-environment.sh"
REACT_NATIVE_XCODE="../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh"

/bin/sh -c "$WITH_ENVIRONMENT $REACT_NATIVE_XCODE"
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but i got this error in bitrise:
+ /bin/sh -c './node_modules/react-native/scripts/xcode/with-environment.sh ./node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh'
/bin/sh: ./node_modules/react-native/scripts/xcode/with-environment.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Weich React and react-native version are you using ?

Comment: I used my script as sample but you need just add ```export NODE_OPTIONS=--openss1-legacy-provider```