# In bitrise , IOS build was failed, Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: node.js, react-native, metro-bundler, bitrise

whenever i try to build my react native app for IOS build, it is giving below mentioned error in bitrise virtual machine (apple silicon, silicon node default version is 18). but when i try to build using my local machine (apple intel, intel node default version is 16) it is working perfectly fine.
[this is the error screenshot in bitrise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKj2p.png)

this is my ios build script

```
``#!/usr/bin/env bash
# fail if any commands fails
set -e
# debug log
set -x

# Set NODE_OPTIONS environment variable for iOS build
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openss1-legacy-provider

# write your script here
find . -type l -exec test ! -e {} \; -delete

#.env update

replace_env_var () {
  sed -i '' "s~$1=.*~$1=$2~g" .env
}

replace_env_var "ENV_DISPLAY_NAME" "v$EURECAB_EM_VERSION"
replace_env_var "API_USER_AGENT" "Eurecab/$EURECAB_EM_VERSION"
replace_env_var "BACKEND_HOST" "$EM_PROD_BACKEND_HOST"
replace_env_var "API_VERSION" "$EM_PROD_API_VERSION"
replace_env_var "ADYEN_ENV" "$EM_PROD_ADYEN_ENV"
replace_env_var "ADYEN_CLIENT_KEY" "$EM_PROD_ADYEN_CLIENT_KEY"
replace_env_var "ADYEN_ENCRYPTION_PUBLIC_KEY" "$EM_PROD_ADYEN_ENCRYPTION_PUBLIC_KEY"
replace_env_var "FIREBASE_PRODUCTION_PROJECT" "true"
replace_env_var "BACKEND_HOST_EDITABLE" "false"
replace_env_var "RECAPCTHA_DOMAIN" "$RECAPCTHA_DOMAIN_PROD"
replace_env_var "RECAPTCHA_KEY" "$RECAPTCHA_KEY_PROD"
```

I have tried this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77643896/in-bitrise-node-js-failed-to-construct-transformer-error-error0308010cdigita](https://stackoverflow.com) solution but its not working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

I need to build my react-native app in bitrise without an error , then only i can able to deploy that app in app store.