# Metro Has Encountered an error: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'transformfile'). ERROR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

Not sure Why I am getting this issue. I am following a react-native tutorial, and am experiencing this error:

```
TransformFile(filePath, transformOptions) {
    var _this3 = this;

    return _asyncToGenerator(function*() {
      // We need to be sure that the DependencyGraph has been initialized.
      // TODO: Remove this ugly hack!
      yield _this3._depGraphPromise;
      return _this3._transformer.transformFile(filePath, transformOptions);
    })();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69649831/12637199 I literally copy paste your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem usually happens because the user is using a node version that's newer. You can solve this by downgrading your node using [Node Version Manager (nvm)](https://nvm.sh).