# React native expo build failed for IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I am trying to make a build for IOS in XCode react native expo but I am getting error while building. Getting *Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported*.
I have searched alot but unable to find any satisfactory answer.

```
 case "$PLATFORM_NAME" in
+ BUNDLE_PLATFORM=ios
+ EMIT_SOURCEMAP=
+ [[ ! -z '' ]]
+ PACKAGER_SOURCEMAP_FILE=
+ [[ '' == true ]]
+ node /Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish/node_modules/react-native/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output /Users/geekybugs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wineish-aevcgwlevyjxsbcpioftvxszdyoo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/wineish/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/geekybugs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wineish-aevcgwlevyjxsbcpioftvxszdyoo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/wineish/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/wineish.app
warning: the transform cache was reset.
                    Welcome to Metro!
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated


watchman warning:  Recrawled this watch 3 times, most recently because:
MustScanSubDirs UserDroppedTo resolve, please review the information on
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#recrawl
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del '/Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish' ; watchman watch-project '/Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish'`

Recrawled this watch 3 times, most recently because:
MustScanSubDirs UserDroppedTo resolve, please review the information on
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#recrawl
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del '/Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish' ; watchman watch-project '/Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish'`

Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at stableHash (/Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stableHash.js:19:8)
    at Object.getCacheKey (/Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:647:7)
    at getTransformCacheKey (/Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/getTransformCacheKey.js:32:19)
    at new Transformer (/Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:180:28)
    at /Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:58:29
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile').
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
    at /Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:95:34
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:14:24)
    at _next (/Users/geekybugs/Documents/wineish/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:36:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I want to understand what is the main cause of this build fail.
This is my package.json file.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && webpack serve",
    "build": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "bundle:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cometchat-pro/react-native-chat": "3.0.2",
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.0.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^8.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.1.12",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.11.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.0.0",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "api": "^6.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-calendar": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-device": "^4.2.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.12.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "mobx": "^6.3.0",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.2.0",
    "mobx-state-tree": "^5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-grid-image-viewer": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.7.3",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.9",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.9.1",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-portalize": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.0.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-shimmer-placeholder": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.0",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "babel-preset-expo": "9.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-handlebarlabs": "^0.0.4",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "wineish",
  "version": "1.6.0"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile') at Bundler.transformFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69647332/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-transformfile-at-bundler-transfo)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to downgrade Node.js to v16.

Comment: alreay using v16.20.1

Comment: Ideally, it should've worked, I had faced something similar previously and this answer suggested the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69699772/11557264