# React Native Expo Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am running into this issue when attempting to build my iOS app in a Release scheme either via Xcode or via the expo CLI. I am able to successfully run the app in the simulator in debug mode.

Error: `Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined`

Some info about my project:

- React Native v0.73.4
- Node v18.17
- Expo v50 (Bare Workflow)

Things I've tried:

- Deleting package-lock.json, node modules, pods, podfile.lock and reinstalling all of them
- Deleting and rebuilding iOS build folder
- Attempted to downgrade to lowest Node version (v18)
- export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider in terminal
- npx expo install --fix this was a fresh project so there wasn't anything

Stacktrace:

```
error: Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined
    at Bundler.transformFile (/Users/[USER]/Documents/Projects/sentiance-expo/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:43:30)
    at async Object.transform (/Users/[USER]/Documents/Projects/sentiance-expo/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:130:12)
    at async transform (/Users/[USER]/Documents/Projects/sentiance-expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:164:26)
    at async visit (/Users/[USER]/Documents/Projects/sentiance-expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:82:29)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async buildSubgraph (/Users/[USER]/Documents/Projects/sentiance-expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:103:3)
    at async Graph._buildDelta (/Users/[USER]/Documents/Projects/sentiance-expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:157:22)
    at async Graph.initialTraverseDependencies (/Users/[USER]/Documents/Projects/sentiance-expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:140:19)
    at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (/Users/[USER]/Documents/Projects/sentiance-expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:151:25)
    at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (/Users/[USER]/Documents/Projects/sentiance-expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:68:16)
```

System Information

```
OS: macOS 13.5.2
  CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
  Memory: 151.78 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.17.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.0/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.15
    path: ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 9.6.7
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.0/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2024.01.22.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.15.2
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.0
      - iOS 17.0
      - macOS 14.0
      - tvOS 17.0
      - watchOS 10.0
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2023.1 AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709
  Xcode:
    version: 15.0/15A240d
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 17.0.10
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.73.4
    wanted: 0.73.4
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
```

Comment: Please update your post with the full stack trace, not just the error message.  The stack trace gives us more context as to where the error is coming from.  Ultimately somewhere in your code or the code of libraries/NPMs you are using, JS is being asked to run `SOMETHING.transformFile`, but `SOMETHING` is undefined.

Comment: BTW: why "bare workflow" ?  I bend over backwards to stick with "managed".  That is a significant portion of the value of Expo.  Unless you are building a new module that involves "native bits", I would encourage you to stick with "managed" (now known as "Continuous Native Generation" (CNG)).

Comment: Thanks @GregFenton, do you know how I can get that stacktrace? Apologies for the silly questions this is my first time using React Native. 

As for why "bare" unfortunately I had to initialize and SDK that required modified native code and I was unable to create an mod that would inject that code into the main ios/android files.

Comment: The full stack tray should be there with the error message you put in your original post. If it isn't there, where are you seeing that error message?

Comment: Ah I see it now, I've added it to the main body. It appears to be coming from the metro node module, specifically Bundler.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69647332/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-transformfile-at-bundler-transfo#:~:text=This%20issue%20is%20due%20to,and%20your%20current%20node%20version.  Found by doing a web search for "bundler error: Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined"

Comment: Yeah I'm on Node 18 which is as low as I can go. I did attempt the solutions in that related SO question already unfortunately.

Comment: There are a lot of stated solutions in that SO post.  Consider reading through all of them. I don't have an M1 so can't say much more.

Comment: Well all of the solutions state downgrading to Node 14-16 which are no longer supported but appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you try deleting your node_modules and reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, I've included some other things I've tried in the post body. Just attempted upgrading to MacOS 14 and that did not work either.